# How to describe durations in text in APA style?

Tags: writing-style

When referring to durations (such as 13 days and two hours), what are rules or correct ways to mention them in-text? Is there a common abbreviation such as 3d 2h or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This information can be found in APA's Publication Manual, as well as their [(7th Ed.) Abbreviations Quick Guide](https://apastyle.apa.org/instructional-aids/abbreviations-guide.pdf):

> 1. Use the time abbreviations shown in the table
>    when they appear with a numeral.
> 2. However, do not abbreviate the following larger
>    units of time, even with numerals:
>
> - Days
> - Weeks
> - Months
> - Years

[image: Table of abbreviations of shorter periods.]

Individual publication avenues or institutions may have their own variations.

Comment: thank you. So when taking the example above we can write "13 days 2 hrs"?

Comment: I believe they treat units of time similarly to other units of measurements, meaning you should not add an 's' to make the unit "plural". Hence, it would be "13 days 2 hr".

Comment: Okay, that makes sense!